# how to print the ouput/error to a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to redirect(?) my standard error/output to a text file.
I did my research, but for some reason the online answers are not working for me.
What am I doing wrong?

```
cd /home/user1/lists/

for dir in $(ls)
do
(
echo | $dir > /root/user1/$dir" "log.txt
) > /root/Desktop/Logs/Update.log
done
```

I also tried

```
2> /root/Desktop/Logs/Update.log
1> /root/Desktop/Logs/Update.log
&> /root/Desktop/Logs/Update.log
```

None of these work for me :(

Help please!

Comment: If plain `echo "test" > /root/Desktop/Logs/Update.log` works -- then the login in Your program is broken.

Comment: I dont' know what you mean by "login".

Comment: Unless every file in your directory is an executable, `echo | $dir` is wrong. What are you trying to accomplish with that?  Anything that `ls /home/user1/lists  > /root/Desktop/Logs/Update.log` does not accomplish?

Comment: Anyway, the primary problem is not with your redirections, but with your syntax in general.

Comment: By the way, `root` should not have a `Desktop`. Log in as yourself, and use `sudo` only sparingly. You want to protect the system both from intruders and from your own mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the basics:

```
echo hello >> log.txt 2>&1
```

Could be read as:  echo the word hello, redirecting and appending STDOUT to the file log.txt. STDERR (file descriptor 2) is redirected to wherever STDOUT is being pointed.  Note that STDOUT is the default and thus there is no "1" in front of the ">>".  Works on the current line only.

To redirect and append all output and error of all commands in a script, put this line near the top.  It will be in effect for the length of the script instead of doing it on each line:

```
exec >>log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: can i do the [exec] to direct STDOUT and STDERR into TWO DIFFERENT FILES??

Comment: exec >> log.txt  # STDOUT  and then exec 2>>log.err #STDERR

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to obtain a list of the files in `/home/user1/lists`, you do not need a loop at all:

```
ls /home/usr1/lists/ >Update.log
```

If you are attempting to run every file in the directory as an executable with a newline as its input, and collect the output from all these programs in `Update.log`, try this:

```
for file in /home/user1/lists/*; do
    echo | "$file"
done >Update.log
```

(Notice how we avoid the [useless use of `ls`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls) and how there is no redirection inside the loop.)

If you want to create an empty file called `*.log.txt` for each file in the directory, you would do

```
for file in /home/user1/lists/*; do
    touch "$(basename "$file")"log.txt
done
```

(Using `basename` to obtain the file name without the directory part avoids the `cd` but you could do it the other way around.  Generally, we tend to avoid changing the directory in scripts, so that the tool can be run from anywhere and generate output in the current directory.)

If you want to create a file containing a single newline, regardless of whether it already exists or not,

```
for file in /home/user1/lists/*; do
    echo >"$(basename "$file")"log.txt
done
```

In your original program, you redirect the `echo` inside the loop, which means that the redirection after `done` will not receive any output at all, so the created file will be empty.

These are somewhat wild guesses at what you might actually be trying to accomplish, but should hopefully help nudge you slightly in the right direction.  (This should properly be a comment, I suppose, but it's way too long and complex.)